# retrieve SQL query containing more than one result

Tags: sql-server, vba

To retrieve a value from a SQL query I usually use the following code:

```
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT...")
strResult = rs.Fields(0)
msgbox(strResult)
```

wich works fine for queries returning one value. For example, if the query result was:

```
LONDON
NEW YORK
BERLIN
```

this will only retrieve "LONDON"

But if I want to obtain all the values from this query, and for example show them on a message box, how can this be done? I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data fetching from SQL Server in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674187/data-fetching-from-sql-server-in-vba)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Loop through recordset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846954/excel-vba-loop-through-recordset)

Answer (score -1):

I think that is better if you use JPA or Hibernate like persistence mechanism. But if you don't like it, I think that the best option for do that is creating an instance of an object and in that object override toString method. Ex:

```
String selectTableSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME from DBUSER";
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

List<User> l = new ArrayList<User>(); //users retrieve from BBDD

ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
    while (rs.next()) {
    String userid = rs.getString("USER_ID");
    String username = rs.getString("USERNAME");
    User u = new User(userid,username); // new USER created
    l.add(u); //add user to list users object
}

for(User u : l){
//Get list of users.
System.out.println(u);
}
```

I hope that I help you

Comment: The OP needs a VBA solution, not C/C++